# Update Date into Null Value SQL

Tags: asp-classic

I have a reset button that goes like this:

```
<% If Request("Reset") = "Reset" Then
Dim cn
Dim strSQLCommand
Set cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open MM_DD_DB_STRING
For Each variableName in Request.Form
    If Instr(variableName, "selected") = "1" Then
        Dim prodCode
        prodCode = Split(variableName, "selected_")(1)

        strSQLCommand = "UPDATE DB.STOCK SET DUE_DATE= NULL WHERE ID=x'" & prodCode & "'"

        cn.Execute strSQLCommand

    End If
Next
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
     End if 

     %>
```

If I click on reset I want the DUE_DATE only to be reset or rather = NULL
For now when I select a checkbox and click reset button it doesn't make the DUE_DATE field into null. But i used this code: `UPDATE DB.STOCK SET DUE_DATE= NULL` Am I doing something wrong?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: do a response.write before the .execute call and see if the values are what you expect                                    `strSQLCommand = "UPDATE DB.STOCK SET DUE_DATE= NULL WHERE ID=x'" & prodCode & "'"
Response.write "strSQLCommand ="&strSQLCommand &"<br>"
'cn.Execute strSQLCommand`

Comment: copy that and try it directly in the db

Answer (score 0):

As SearchAndResQ are suggesting in his comment to your question: Do a quick response.write before the execute call, do see if the query looks correct. If it looks fine, do a quick check directly into the database, to check if it accepts it.

Lastly check to see if your .asp site isn't errored. I suspect this, because you are doing a definition of a variable (`dim prodCode`) inside a for-loop, which will cause the page to error if the loop is repeated 2 or more times. Move this line outside the for-loop.